# Register type library x64 regtlib

Tags: 64-bit, typelib, regtlib

I'm running Windows 7 x64, and need to register a type library file (.tlb).  I've done this previously (on a Vista x64 machine) but neglected to take notes as to how I achieved it...

There is no regtlib.exe / regtlibv12.exe on the system.  I have copied across the regtlibv12.exe from a Windows XP system, however this will "not run".

I have also attempted to register the TLB via "regsvr32" (tried using both the 32 and 64 bit versions) however always get the "Windows system mismatch" error.

I have been performing these operations using an elevated privilege command prompt.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7):

I used http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Utilities/Type_Library_Registration_Utility/article.html

running as admin. Also includes source code if you're curious what's required.

As of 2019, the utility can be downloaded here: https://github.com/tannerhelland/vbAccelerator-Archive/tree/master/VB/Utilities/Type_Library_Registration_Utility

Comment: The download links on that site seem to be broken.

Comment: The utility is supper handy; includes source code and standalone exe - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Regasm only works for TLB files generated for .NET assemblies. So, you have to use regtlibv12.exe
You can find this file in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 if you have Visual Studion 2010 installed.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, I know, but I thought I'd share what worked for me in case it helps anyone else out.

I needed to register a TLB on Windows Server 2008.  I installed the .NET 4.0 framework to get the regtlibv12.exe and that worked.  I believe the regtlibv12.exe is also available in the Windows SDK.

Answer (score -2):

`regtlibv12.exe` is not available on Win10 platforms.  It has been replaced with `TlbExp.exe` as found in the corresponding .NET SDK (e.g. `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools\x64\TlbExp.exe" "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)"`
see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/tlbexp-exe-type-library-exporter).